# I get attribute error during convert float to int

Tags: pandas

```
Earliest_year = df['Birth Year'].min().astype('int64')

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

how to apply code correctly

Comment: First you must show a sample of your data. Secondly, when you do `.min()` it gives you a single value. In this case it is float. If you want to convert the resulting value to int. Try this.
`int(df['Birth Year'].min())`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you are taking minimum its a float value thats why as type does not work.

Please use int(value) to convert to int

```
int(dataframe_name['column_name'].min())
```